# XML: Retrieve a particular value from xml

Tags: c#, xml

From the following XML, I want to find a value based on the Employer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Details>
        <Employer>Taxes</Employer>
        <Adr>
            <Strt>Street</Strt>
            <Twn>Town</Twn>
        </Adr>
    </Details>
    <DetailsAcct>
        <Recd>
            <Payroll>
                <Id>9</Id>
            </Payroll>
        </Recd>
        <br>
            <xy>A</xy>
        </br>
    </DetailsAcct>
</Document>
```

the C# code I applied is

```
  detail = root.SelectSingleNode($"//w:Document//w:Employer[contains(text(), 'Taxes']/ancestor::Employer",nsmgr);
```

But it gives me an `invalid token` error.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Wanted to get back the employer who has the name as Taxes

Comment: Why are you using a `w:` namespace prefix when your XML is in no namespace?

Answer (score 3):

The error was due to `[contains(...]`, notice closing parentheses is missing. And since you want to return `Employer` element, no need for `ancestor::Employer` here :

```
//w:Document//w:Employer[contains(., 'Taxes')]
```

If the XML posted resembles structure of the actual XML (except the namespaces), better to use more specific XPath i.e avoid using costly `//` :

```
/w:Document/w:Details/w:Employer[contains(., 'Taxes')]
```

Comment: All true, but you might also want to question the use of a namespace prefix (`w:`) where no namespace is used in the XML.

Comment: In the Xml there are many <Employer> nodes. I need to retrieve a specific node which contains "Taxes"

Comment: Tried the following                           /w:Document/w:Details/w:Employer[contains(., 'Taxes')]/ancestor::Employer",nsmgr    But returns "null"

Comment: @vicky `w:Employer[contains(., 'Taxes')]` already covered that, no need for `ancestor::Employer`.

Comment: @vicky Now, that I failed to 'guess' the situation correctly (that the XPath suggested turned out to be not working for your actual XML), I'd suggest to post *minimal but complete* XML sample that would demonstrate how the above XPath failed i.e returns `null`. Make sure people can easily copy-paste the XML and test it against the codes/XPath

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

If the XML is in a string:

```
string xml = "<xml goes here>";
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement element = document.Descendants("Employer").First();
string value = element.Value;
```

If the XML is in a .xml file:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");
XElement element = document.Descendants("Employer").First();
string value = element.Value;
```

You can also find an employer element with a specific value, if that's what you need:

```
XElement element = document.Descendants("Employer").First(e => e.Value == "Taxes");
```

Note: this will throw an exception if no element is found with the specified value. If that is not acceptable, then you can replace .First(...) with .FirstOrDefault(...) which will simply return null if no element is found.